Laplace Operator and Inversion
Let us consider the inversion $J$ (center $0$, ratio $1$) from $\mathbb R^d\backslash\{0\}$ into itself given by
$$
J(x)=\frac{x}{\vert x\vert^2}.
$$
Considering a smooth function $v$ on $\mathbb R^d\backslash\{0\}$, I define $w$
on $\mathbb R^d\backslash\{0\}$ by
$$
w(y)=v(J(y)).
$$
I want to calculate explicitly the expression $(∆v)(x)$ in terms of derivatives of $w$. This is an elementary computation, but that would be a relief to find a reference where this computation is performed.
